# Calculating cells values in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid (written in Romanian):

[image]

I want to calculate the column "Valoarea" by this formula:

> valoarea = *Cantitatea* * *Pret unitar (fara T.V.A.)*

My actual code gives me error:

```
private void produseFacturate_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 3:
                var row = produseFacturate.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                double qty, price;

                double.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out qty);
                double.TryParse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out price);

                row.Cells[4].Value = (qty * price).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now, my question is: How can I populate that specific cell on row with the good data?

Comment: do you have existing code that when you are on that particular record that it will get the rows.column data and there you can capture it in variables to do the calculation. question is are you wanting to calculate on `Cell Enter` or `Cell Exit`, based on if `Valoarea T.V.A.` value is empty or null..

Comment: I don't believe that the data grid has any sort of calculation engine built into it (it's not a spreadsheet). In my class I would just make Valoarea a read-only property, and just calculate the value in the getter.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, you understood my problem. it is that I do not know how to get that particular cell

Comment: Do you have any existing code at the moment..? if so post the code where you are selecting from the DataGridView from there I am quite sure we can help you

Comment: see in my edit. it gives the ArgumentOutOfRangeException for parameters `index`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the control is actually a DataGridView?

You could override the CellFormatting event. Here's a simple example:

I created a DataGridView with 3 columns.

```
this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.Column3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Column1,
        this.Column2,
        this.Column3});

this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(405, 150);
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

And I want to make the 3rd column the product of the first two. Here's my method to override the cellformatting.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Column3"))
            {
                try {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value =  Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
```

Note that whenever I change a value in the 1st two columns, the 3rd is recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wondering how to compute value in datagridview's cells and put the result on another column of the same row, at the datagridview's CellEndEdit event you can try this way:

```
 if (Convert.ToDecimal(datagridPR.CurrentRow.Cells["price_value"].Value) != 0)
        {
            decimal c_Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(datagridPR.CurrentRow.Cells["quantity"].Value);
            decimal c_Result = c_Quantity * Convert.ToDecimal(datagridPR.CurrentRow.Cells["price_value"].Value);
            datagridPR.CurrentRow.Cells["amount"].Value = c_Result;
        }
```

Every time you press enter or leave the cell after editing, the result of the computation can be seen at the amount column immediately. You may extend the code to handle null values to avoid a runtime error.